# Removing jquery imgareaselect plugin from element

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui-dialog, img-area-select-jquery

So im using this neat jquery plugin http://odyniec.net/projects/imgareaselect/
It works fine, but i'm firing it with jquery ui callback function (dialog), and i need to remove the selection after dialog closes.

```
function initialize_selection() {
$('#image_area').imgAreaSelect({ x1: 10, y1: 10, x2: $('#image_area').width()-10, y2: $('#image_area').height()-10 , fadeSpeed: 400, handles: true});
}

$(function() {
$('#image_edit').click(function(){
    $('#edit_image_dialog').load('actions.php?action=edit_temp_image', function(){
            $('#edit_image_dialog').dialog({
                modal: true,
                resizable: false,
                width: 480,
                    buttons: {
            Ok: function() {
                        //foo_bar                                                                        
            },
                        Cancel: function() {
                        //foo_bar
            }
                    },
                    beforeclose: function(){
                    //What should i put here ???
                    ;}
            });
    initialize_selection();
        });
    });
});
```

I would really appreciate some tips, because i'm new to jquery and I can't work this out by myself.

Thank you

Comment: Not sure, but +1 to the question for sharing a very cool jQuery plugin!

Answer (score 22):

http://odyniec.net/projects/imgareaselect/usage.html

```
$('#image_area').imgAreaSelect({remove:true});
```

should work, but not sure

Answer (score 6):

The only way I've found to get the selection treatment areas removed was the following:

```
"Close": function() { 
  $(".imgareaselect-selection").parent().remove();
  $(".imgareaselect-outer").remove();
  $(this).dialog("close"); 
},
```

The following did not work for me (in the jquery and jqueryui elements in Wordpress 3.0.5)

```
$(selector).imgAreaSelect( {remove: true} );
```

Comment: +1 . 

$(selector).imgAreaSelect( {remove: true} ); didn't work for me.

Answer (score 5):

This worked for me:

```
var $ias = $('#imageArea').imgAreaSelect({
    instance: true
});

$('#clearBtn2').click(function() {
    $ias.cancelSelection();
});
```

Comment: This is a better answer if you want to re-open your dialog and do the image area select again. @Daniele's answer will completely remove/destroy the plugin from your element, but this will simply remove the visual selection box and background.

Answer (score 3):

According to the documentation for the options at [HomeimgAreaSelect Documentation](http://odyniec.net/projects/imgareaselect/usage.html#options)

```
$('#image_area').imgAreaSelect( {remove: true} );
```

will do the trick

Answer (score 1):

According to the documentation: http://odyniec.net/projects/imgareaselect/usage.html

{remove: true} will actually remove the imgAreaSelect-y-ness completely.  If all you want to do is box and grayed out area, (but allow the user to drag a new box later) you want {hide: true}.

```
$('#image_area').imgAreaSelect( {hide: true} );
```

Answer (score 1):

```
$('#image_area').imgAreaSelect({remove:true}); //For hiding the imagearea
$('#image_area').imgAreaSelect({remove:false}); //For resetting the imagearea
```

First statement hides the imgareaselect and the second statement helps in reloading the crop functionality when the modal is loaded the next time.

I used both the statements while returning to the main window from the modal so that there is no issue loading the crop functionality next time.

Answer (score 0):

ya it really work but after  -->$('#image_area').imgAreaSelect({remove:true}); 
It cannot work on tagging other photo