# Remove/disable jquery plugin on button click

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I am using [jQuery ImageAreaSelect](http://odyniec.net/projects/imgareaselect/) for image area selection like this:

```
 $('#image').imgAreaSelect({}); //#image is a img id
```

Below this image, I have a bunch of image thumbnails, clicking on which will populate that image as `#image`. This way user can load each image and then select its area.

My problem is that when a new image is loaded, the dotted line which indicates the area selected for previous image still remains and gets shown on the newly loaded image. I do not want this and want this to go away every time a new image is loaded.

I read and tried [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2386998/removing-jquery-imgareaselect-plugin-from-element) and [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3709633/jquery-imgareaselect-hide-show) but they are not working for me... 
My current (non-working) code is:

```
$('#load').click(function() {
    $('#image').imgAreaSelect({hide:true,remove:true}); //try to remove old instance
    $('#image').imgAreaSelect({}); //create new instance...
});
```

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: http://odyniec.net/projects/imgareaselect/usage.html#options

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have never used such pluggin but the documentation explains [how to disable/re-enable it.](http://odyniec.net/projects/imgareaselect/usage.html)

Save the variable when you initialize the pluggin

```
var ias = $('#image').imgAreaSelect( // your original initalization
```

Then call disable on it as the documentation states:

```
ias.setOptions({hide:true,remove:true})
```

Comment: Ok, when I gave `instance:true` in the original instantiation it worked... I also had to do `ias.update()` after setting the hide option

Answer (score 0):

Try this way

```
$('#load').click(function() {
    $('#image').cancelSelection();
});
```